# How best to check connectivity of web server to database?

Tags: iis, sql-server, monitoring

Our IT admin is asking for an api endpoint in our web application to use as a health check. The logic in the api should perform any simple database query to ensure that the web server can connect to the database. The idea is that a fail of this api call can trigger automatic decommissioning of the web server, etc.

This will definitely work, but seems a bit home made. Is there a better way using out of box tooling etc to achieve this? We are on the Microsoft stack so the web boxes are IIS 8 and the database is SQL 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as you propose, however you'll need to make the api call at regular intervals from "somewhere". You'll still have undesired behavior during the time between when the DB goes down and the next ping detects it.

Another solution is to catch the error in a global handler. (In ASP.NET you can do this in the Global.asax file.) You could inspect the error and get pretty granular if you'd like, such as taking one action if the connection to the DB has timed out, or another action if the connection is valid but there is a permissions error. Note that a DB connection error will only make it to the global handler if something else doesn't handle it first.

Suggestion: try to make the "what you do about it" portion a separate mechanism from the detection method. That way you could even implement both ideas, or a third, and share the same resulting actions.

Comment: Helpful suggestion, like the application level detection better. Thanks!